# Differences between gcc versions 4 and 5 and 6

Tags: c++, c, gcc

When downloading sources for an `arm` cross-compiler I found that there are several versions of gcc in maintenance. Latest builds are v4.9.4, v5.4.0 and v6.2.0.

Why is there a v4 that is more recent than the latest release of v5 and the first release of v6 and what are the major differences between these versions?

[image: GNU GCC Repo]

Comment: Read the release notes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The older versions receive bug fixes only, while new features are implemented in the newer versions. From https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html:

> The table is sorted by date. Note that starting with version 3.3.4, we provide bug releases for older release branches for those users who require a very high degree of stability.

If you like it graphicly (ASCII-ART): https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline

Comment: so it is fair to say that `gcc 5.4.0` is a superset of `gcc 4.9.4` and `gcc 4.9.4` is not outperforming `gcc 5.4.0` by any means? (EDIT: superset in terms of features)

Comment: no. gcc has dropped support for some languages in the past, gcc probably (idk) has dropped support for some optimization methods, possibly gcc has dropped support for some weird architectues and so on. But that shouldn't be the point. The point is: Does the older (and hence more stable) compiler do it's job? If yes, just use it, you can still upgrade later.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a c++ question.

Developers are actively working on all of those versions at the same time. If one of those versions needs a bug fix then it will be patched and updated.

Is that what you mean?

Versions 4, 5 & 6 have newer C++ features, for example, I think 5 has std++14 and 6 has std++1z (you can search google for the features in each standard)